# Search through document and find all inputs with titles

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to search through my document, and find all inputs with `title` attribute, but at the same the `title` attribute can not be empty. So it should look for every input with title attribute that has at least one character in length.

Then I would like to make some event on those inputs (like add them some CSS class).

Is that even possible with jQuery or other javascript library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("input[title]").not('[title=""]')
```

Comment: This answer works perfectly. Your jsfiddle example isn't using quotes correctly in the `addClass` method.

Comment: @Dr.Molle, is that possible to make something like: `set input value same as its title` with your example?

Comment: Yes, use each: `$("input[title]").not('[title=""]').each(function(){$(this).val($(this).attr('title'));});`

Comment: or this, may be faster: `$("input[title]").not('[title=""]').val(function(){return $(this).attr('title');});`

Answer (score 3):

I believe this would give you what you want:

```
$('input[title][title!=""]')
```

To apply css

```
$('input[title][title!=""]').addClass('class1 class2 class3');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5hkAG/

Comment: +1 - Way better than an each statement. However, OP should keep in mind that this will return titles that contain only spaces: `<input title=" ">`

Comment: How can I apply a CSS class on it ?

Comment: This selector will also find input's without a title-attribute

Comment: you should call `addClass('test')`

Answer (score 1):

```
var myInputs = [];

$("input").each(function() {
    if($(this).attr("title").length > 0) {
        myInputs.push(this);
        // do other events as usual, using $(this) as selector for current input
    }
});

// do something with myInputs, which is an array of all inputs with a title attribute
```